# ros::init(…) throws an error - Windows roscpp

Tags: roscpp, windows

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use ros in cpp with Visual Studio 2012. I wrote the publisher and subscriber tutorial (http:// wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29) and first, I configure the project as says in the guide (http:// wiki.ros.org/win_ros/hydro/Msvc%20SDK%20Projects).

Then i compiled an linked the publisher, but when I tried to run it, ros::init(argc,argv,"talker") throws an exception... The console says that I ROS_MASTER_URI is not defined but I've got it defined

There are 2 images here: https:// [www.dropbox.com/s/o12m0l38gaxiugi/error1.png](http://www.dropbox.com/s/o12m0l38gaxiugi/error1.png) - https:// [www.dropbox.com/s/ocdmf0wj6rj0962/error.png](http://www.dropbox.com/s/ocdmf0wj6rj0962/error.png)

Can anyone helps me?

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/132856/ros::init(%E2%80%A6)-throws-an-error---windows-roscpp/) by [Bardo](https://answers.ros.org/users/12396/bardo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-02-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

in my case, I have used the system environment variable to export ROS_MASTER_URI
you can use windows system variable to set the variable ROS_MASTER_URI

open the environment variable setting windows ,
windows start -> control pane -> system -> advanced setting

click New button, and put ROS_MASTER_URI as variable name, and put the http://localhost:11311/ as its value.

and open the new DOS terminal, launch roscore.
roscore will be operated well.

good luck.

---

Originally posted by [Injun Park](https://answers.ros.org/users/8646/injun-park/) with karma: 26 on 2014-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lilouch](https://answers.ros.org/users/21904/lilouch/) on 2015-04-20**:
I did that but I still have the same problem. I really don't understand why...